# Manifold - why doesn't locally Euclidean property imply Hausdorff condition?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Definition: Manifold $M$ is second-countable Hausdorff space which is locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space.

Suppose only locally Euclidean property. Take 2 points, $p$ and $q$ and maps $(U, \varphi)$ and $(V, \phi)$ around $p$ and $q$. Now if sets are disjoint, we are done.

If $q\in U$, since $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism with $R^n$ (or its open subset), we can just take disjoint open sets there (since $\varphi(p)\neq\varphi(q)$) and pull them back in the manifold.

If $U\cap V \neq \emptyset$, then obviously $\phi(U\cap V)$ and $\varphi(U \cap V)$ are open in $R^n$ and $\varphi(p)$ and $\phi(q)$ are not in it. So again, take open neighbourhoods of mapped points disjoint from mapped intersection, pull them back and you get Hausdorff condition.

Where is the mistake in this reasoning? Can one also give counterexample of locally Euclidean space which is not Hausdorff.

Comment: In "If $U \cap V \ne \emptyset$", I assume you mean separately to consider the case $p \in V$, and then to consider the case where $U \cap V \ne \emptyset$ but $p \notin V$ and $q \notin U$?  In that case, what do you mean by "open neighbourhoods of mapped points disjoint from mapped intersection"?  Also, what is "it" in "$\varphi(p)$ and $\phi(q)$ are not in it"?  You have two sets ($\phi(U \cap V)$ and $\varphi(U \cap V)$).

Comment: Yes, $p\in V$ is analogous to the case $q\in U$. I meant that $\varphi(p) \notin \varphi(U\cap V)$ (since $p\notin U\cap V$ and $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism) and same for $\phi(q)$ .

Comment: [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401721/manifold-why-doesnt-locally-euclidean-property-imply-hausdorff-condition#comment9207313_4401721), so $\varphi(p) \notin \varphi(U \cap V)$ and $\phi(q) \notin \phi(U \cap V)$, but the problem is that $\varphi(U \cap V)$ and $\phi(U \cap V)$ are different sets in different copies of $\mathbb R^n$; they may not necessarily be regarded as disjoint subsets of a common $\mathbb R^n$ containing $\varphi(p)$ and $\phi(q)$, which seems to be what you are picturing.  That's why I ask what you mean by "it", singular.

Answer (score 4):

The error lies in “take open neighbourhoods of mapped points disjoint from mapped intersection”.

Take $X=\Bbb R\times\{1,-1\}$. Consider in this space the equivalence relation $(x,a)\sim(y,b)$ if and only if $x=y$ and $x,y\ne0$. That is, you identify $(x,1)$ with $(x,-1)$ unless $x=0$, but $(0,1)\not\sim(0,-1)$. Then $X/{\sim}$, endowed with the quotient topology, is locally Euclidean but it is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Thank you, but can you perhaps just give a bit more details? What is the topology on your space and the definition of a map to $R^n$ for some $n$? I suppose the map is projection on first coordinate, but what happens with $(0, 1)$ and $(0, -1)$? We do need to have a homeomorphism

Comment: The space is given its quotient topology.  The projections of $\mathbb R \times \{1\}$ and $\mathbb R \times \{-1\}$ on $\mathbb R$ are both homeomorphisms.

Comment: I agree that this is a counterexample, but I'm not sure that the error is where you say.  In this case, with an obvious choice of $(U, \varphi)$ and $(V, \phi)$, we have that $\varphi(U \cap V)$ happens to equal $\phi(U \cap V)$ (which is not always true!), and, in fact, $\varphi(p)$ and $\phi(q)$ (not $\varphi(q)$, which isn't defined) indeed both don't lie in that  common set.  I think the issue is actually with the somewhat vague "take open neighbourhoods of mapped points disjoint from mapped intersection."

Comment: @LSpice You are right! I've edited my answer. Thank you.